# Pytube error. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

I'm working on a Python YouTube downloader, a very simple task. I used pytube for a while and never encountered this error. My code is the following:

```
from pytube import YouTube
import pytube
yt_title = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjDZrReZ4EI').title
ytd = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjDZrReZ4EI').streams.first().download()
```

The error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    ytd = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjDZrReZ4EI').streams.first().download()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'
```

These are the especifications:

```
Name: pytube
Version: 10.0.0
Summary: Python 3 library for downloading YouTube Videos.
Home-page: https://github.com/nficano/pytube
Author: Nick Ficano, Harold Martin
Author-email: nficano@gmail.com, harold.martin@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: 'location of the package'
Requires: typing-extensions
Required-by:
```

The video I'm using is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjDZrReZ4EI

Something that I realized is that some videos that I was able to download a few hours before now I cannot. I just uninstalled pytube and installed pytube3. But now I get the following error:

```
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_ytplayer_config: could not find match 
for config_patterns
```

It doesn't let me download any video.

Comment: errors means that `first()` gives `None` and you can try to do  `None.download()`. You should firts get `first()` and check if it is not `None` before you use `download()

Comment: if you can't download some videos then you should check in web brower if they still exist on YouTube - maybe they were removed. OR youtube recognized that it is script and block you as a bot/spamer/hacker

Answer (score 1):

You will have to uninstall **pytube** and install **pytube3** using pip. If it does not work then print streams and see if you are getting streams

```
yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjDZrReZ4EI')
print(yt.streams)
```

Comment: I just uninstalled pytube and installed pytube3. When i try to running it it gives me the following error: pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_ytplayer_config: could not find match for config_patterns

Comment: https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/614#issuecomment-724326141
You can try this one, btw pytube version 10.1.0 solves the problem